# Change Powershell Execution Policy silently from Batch script

Tags: command-line, powershell

I would like some help on setting a registry value for powershell. The path is

> [hkey_local_machine\system32\windows\microsoft\powershell\1\shellids\microsoft.powershell]
>   "Path"="c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
>   "ExecutionPolicy"="unrestricted"

Since I have imported this from a known good machine,when I run the .reg file it works fine. But I would like this in a batch file.

When I manually call the command prompt, drop in the path e.g `c:\powershell.reg`, this imports the values and overwrites the the registry settings as required.
 However if l call do the same thing in a batch file, the values are not changed in the registry
Using the reg add command in a batch file the values does not work.

Comment: “Does not work” is not a sufficient description of what’s happening.

Comment: Hi  perhaps I should have provided a little information. So in essence if I manually call the command prompt, drop in the path  e.g c:\powershell.reg, this imports the values and overwrites the the registry settings as required. However if l call do the same thing in a batch file, the values are not changed in the registry. So batch files is as simple as

Comment: Is group policy not an option?

Answer (score 12):

Why not simply run the following via CMD

```
powershell -command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force}"
```

or this directly in Powershell (that's what the command is for after all):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I change Powershell Execution Policy silently from a batch script?

Warning:

The instructions below contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly.

Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.

For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

---

#### `reg` solution

```
@echo off
reg add HKLM\system32\windows\microsoft\powershell\1\shellids\microsoft.powershell /v "Path" /d "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
reg add HKLM\system32\windows\microsoft\powershell\1\shellids\microsoft.powershell /v "ExecutionPolicy" /d "unrestricted"
```

---

#### `regedit` solution

```
@echo off
regedit /s file.reg
```

Where `file.reg` contains the following:

```
[hkey_local_machine\system32\windows\microsoft\powershell\1\shellids\microsoft.powershell] 
"Path"="c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
"ExecutionPolicy"="unrestricted"
```

Note:

- `[/s|-s]`

  When a filename is specified on the command line, this switch is used to suppress any informational dialog boxes that would normally be displayed. This is useful when the Setup program for an application wants to execute REGEDIT.EXE with a .REG file, but does not want the user to be confused by any dialog boxes that are displayed.

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.
- [regedit](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) - Import, export or delete registry settings from a text (.REG) file.
- [regedit](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/82821) - Command-line switches.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the Regedit.exe /s command and that failed. I will give that another go. Thank you